# Database Relationship between tables that depends on same table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a very specific database. This Database contains 4 tables.

I have a component table. This component table will always have a system.
The system may have multiple subsystem.
Each subsystem could have multiple parts.

This means that in order to have a part, I must have a subsystem and to have that subsystem I must have a system.

One part is always related with one subsystem, and that subsystem will be always related to just one system.

The problem comes with the component... Because it is mandatory to have a system, but not a subsystem hence not a part.

If I create a relationship between the part and the component I will be able to know which subsystem and also the system in the relation. But what happen when I have just a system? This way I won't be able to retrieve the system.

My idea was to relate subsystem and also system directly with the components. Having a total of 3 relationships at components. But that way, if I have a part, then the relationships between subsystem and components will contain information that is already present in the part-component relationship. And the same with the system-component relationship.

How can I remove the duplicated information?

**EDIT**

To make it easier to read I will copy the summary made by @duffymo but with one correction:

1. Four entities: Component, System, Subsystem, and Part
2. Component-System is 1:many
3. System-Subsystem is 0:many
4. Subsystem-Part is 0:many

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the beginning with entity relationships.

I read this:

1. Four entities: Component, System, Subsystem, and Part
2. Component-System is 1:many
3. System-Subsystem is 0:many
4. Subsystem-Part is 0:many

It's the "may have" in the last two that causes the problem.

The problem comes about when you have a System that is a single Part: No System or Subsystem intervening.

It might be that you circumvent the problem by making Component-Part many-to-many.  I don't see a distinction between System and Subsystem.  I'd just have System.

Comment: Another comment. If I create a component-part N:M that means that my component can have multiple parts, that is wrong.

Comment: There is a distinction between System and Subsystem. The system information will never be the same as subsystem. I don't need a subsystem to be a system. As an example: system can be a camera, and the subsystem could be the lens. You wont have a camera inside a camera, and we will never have lens outside a camera as per requeriments

Comment: Semantics.  I could just as easily call a lens a System.  I can think of a Part as a leaf node in a graph and a System as a collection of Parts.  Graphs are a natural way to represent a bill of materials.

Comment: Please provide an example of a Subsystem with 0 Parts.

Comment: In our case, we shall store in the database a small satellite, that has an electrict system that we are not building for ourself. This will be a subsystem inside the system that has no part. Satellite <-- System. EPS <-- Subsystem. We have plans that sooner or later we build a different EPS. That one will have parts. But as for today, that is not the case

Comment: I'd say that vendor electrical thingy without parts could just as easily be called a Part, be a leaf node in the graph, and eliminate the problem.  You're trapped by your fuzzy language and ideas.

Comment: It could be... but in my defense, it is my boss language and ideas. I guess it would be easier using "Project" instead of "System". "System" instead of "Subsystem" and leave part as it is. Right now, my boss, has information about the projects she wants to store. But not all projects have all its system defined, neither does all the possible parts of a system.

Comment: Then you'll continue to have this problem.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help provided :)

Comment: Your schema forces you to add an Subsystem for the sake of being able to add a leaf Part to a System.  That's the only downside I see.

Comment: I think I will just merge everything in the same table. System, subsystem and part. 4 columns, id + the other 3. id being the primary key, and the table having a UNIQUE index that consists of the 3 other columns to avoid duplicated values. Then, via the web application, I will create queries to retrieve the information, first all the possible Systems, then I will retrieve the subsystems using an Ajax call and do the same with the part once the subsystem has been selected.